# Is there a way to make a button fade as you scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bouncing down arrow at the bottom of the screen of my website (the button part isn't completed yet, but the visual part is there) that stays in the same spot when you scroll down the page.

This is the code for the button:

```css
@keyframes bouncing {
    0% {bottom: 0;}
    50% {bottom: 10px;}
    100% {bottom: 0;}
}

.arrow {
    animation: bouncing 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="arrow" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png"/>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the arrow fade out when you scroll down the page in JS or CSS?

thanks

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Mahdi-Jafaree's answer, which is fine but only 'hides' and 'shows' the arrow instead of fading it, I tweaked the code a bit.

```js
let opacityPercentage = 100;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const arrowElement = document.getElementById('arrow');
  
  window.onscroll = () => {
    opacityPercentage = Math.max(100 - window.pageYOffset, 0);
    arrowElement.style.opacity = opacityPercentage / 100;
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes bouncing {
    0% {bottom: 0;}
    50% {bottom: 10px;}
    100% {bottom: 0;}
}

.arrow {
    animation: bouncing 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200vh;"> 
  <div>
      <img class="arrow" id="arrow" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-128.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I would try this code and the code in the earlier answer, but I'm currently having trouble with uploading the .js file to the local server :( .

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `window.onscroll` to listen which offset position you are when there is an scroll event.
here is a solution for hiding you image when scrolled to down with javascript:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function () {
  console.log("scrolled");
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos) {
    console.log(prevScrollpos, currentScrollPos);
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    console.log(prevScrollpos, currentScrollPos);
    document.getElementById("arrow").style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

note: You need to add an id with value of `arrow` to your image tag.
also here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/exciting-engelbart-mlzde0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for sample code.